# Download multiple files as folder with JavaScript and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Goal: I have an array of `<a>` that I loop through to download with `element.click`. With this method, the files are downloaded 1 by 1. I would rather them be downloaded in a folder instead, as the array can reach up to 3 digit lengths.

Is this possible on the client side?

Current Code:

```
                <button onClick={ () => {
                    projectScreens.forEach( (item, index) => {
                        htmlToImage.toJpeg(document.getElementById(index + 'Export'), { pixelRatio: 6 })
                            .then(function (dataUrl) {
                                const link = document.createElement('a');
                                link.download = 'Screen ' + (index + 1) + '.jpeg';
                                link.href = dataUrl;
                                link.click();
                            });
                    });
                }}>export</button>
```

(htmlToImage.toJpeg just converts an element in the DOM into jpeg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser/HTTP does not support downloading more than one file at a time.

There are 2 solutions:

- Write a script to zip the files (Preferred way)
- Open multiple windows that triggers download for each file

However, there is a tool that might be your help. Check this out https://github.com/sindresorhus/multi-download